# Questions about Time complexity O(1), O(n), O(log n), O(n log n)

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

I am currently studying time complexity of arraylist especially about access and search. And I am little confused about which one is which.

1. So I know that time complexity of access(when you know index) is O(1).

But are 2 and 3 correct??

2. Search on the arraylist when the arraylist is sorted and you do not know that index is O(n)...?
3. Time complexity When you need to find data from unsorted arraylist and you do not know its index is O(n)...?

Should answer for 2 and 3 be same? or sorted / unsorted arraylist would change the time complexity?

Comment: #2 and #3 sound like they're the same thing: search for data in an unsorted arraylist.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. So (2) should be search from sorted arraylist(index unknown) and (3) should be search from unsorted arraylist(index unknown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a linear search through an arraylist, you are looking for some element. Since you don't know what index the data is at, you have to go through every element until you find the item you are looking for.

In the worst case, you have to go all the way until the last element. Big Oh works as an upper bound on the algorithm. In the worst case, we have to go through all n elements, so the algorithm is O(n).

If the arraylist was sorted, you could use a binary search which is O(log n)

Comment: thank you so much for the fast reply! I get that Time complexity for sorted arraylist with binary search would be O(lon n). But if you do  just search rather than binary search from sorted arraylist, should it be O(n)?

Comment: yes is still would be since you could be searching for the last element still

Answer (score 3):

For #2, it depends on how you're doing the search. If you do a sequential search, e.g. using [`indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), then performance is *O(n)*, regardless of whether the data is sorted or not.

Searching a *sorted* list or array can be done in ***O(log n)*** using a *binary search algorithm*.

Doing a binary search on a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) can be done using [`Collections.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#i2). As the javadoc says:

> This method runs in *log(n)* time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs *O(n)* link traversals and *O(log n)* element comparisons.

Doing a binary search on an array can be done using [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i1).